# laptop not wakening from sleep Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, suspend

I am using a framework 12th gen laptop with an i5-1240P intel processor. I haven been using it for 3 months and randomly the laptop while contacted to power will not wake from sleep. I have no capslock light, the keyboard and power button are unresponsive. This only happens when plunged in to power.

Only way I have found to recover is to hold power button for 5 to 10 seconds and hard reboot.

I would love help in finding ways to debug this or any ideas to try.

-- Update further trouble shooting notes --

I can change the keyboard backlight.

I can't get to the tty.

*Sometimes* if I lave my laptop long enough it will recover.

I used fwupd to update my firmware

Comment: Look at the logs, see the end of the previous boot's logs with the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: did you mean journalctl   -b 1 -ex?

Comment: So i looked into my logs, but nothing seemed out of the ordinary is the something particular I'm looking for? Everything shows as green and finished.